# Building war with Gradle, Debugging with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

I have JavaEE webapp project(named ProjectA) developed in IntelliJ IDEA.It has *build.gradle* file that applies war plugin :

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```

I want to debug(or run) **gradle generated war file** instead of debugging **auto generated intellij artifact**.
It's very important for me that I can update classes changed during debugging without need to restart server.

[image]

How can I do it?

Note that :

1) When click refresh button in gradle plugin tab ([image: refresh all Gradle peojects]) Intellij updates all project configurations(for example module dependencies) and generate artifacts.I called it **auto generated intellij artifact**.
[image]

For run it,I should only create new local Tomcat Server configuration and add artifact to deployment tab.
[image]

[image]

2) In addition,there is some gradle tasks(clean,build,war and etc).I can execute *build task* or *war task* to generate war file.I called it **gradle generated war file**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of deploying the IntelliJ build artifact, you can deploy an "External source" by clicking the "+" button in your final screenshot. You can then navigate to the artifact built by Gradle (in this case, the .war file in build/libs).

Second, you can instruct IntelliJ to run a Gradle task before running the configuration. Again, in your final screenshot, I would remove the second step labeled "Build 'Gradle ...' artifact" and add a step to run the Gradle `war` task.

Comment: Thank you.It's work but don't support **reload classes** during debugging.The question was edited to support this feature.

Comment: Reload classes should still be supported using this method when debugging. Just recompile using IntelliJ (CTRL+F9).

Comment: Can anyone see the screenshots above?  Were they taken down?  Which dialog was the final screenshot of, for putting in the external source?