# Unable to make the module: related gradle configuration was not found. Please, re-import the Gradle project and try again

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, project-structure

I use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14 and Gradle 1.2. I manage the project from the console, but I need to debug some of the code from the IDE.

When I try to make the project, [this error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ5L5.gif) appears. When I try to debug the project,

```
Error: Unable to make the module: idappcli, related Gradle configuration was not found. 
Please, re-import the Gradle project and try again.
```

is written in the message window. How can I add the regular output paths to the project?

Answer (score 259):

Try by opening the [gradle task view](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gradle-tool-window.html) and then click the refresh button. For me it solved the problem.

Comment: When you import the gradle project there is an "auto-import" checkbox.

Comment: You can show the view by clicking `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Gradle` in the main menu next to `File` and `Edit`.

Comment: Has no effect for me on 15.0.2.

Comment: I still use this trick on my IntelliJ 2016.2.1 and it works without problems. Be aware that you need to wait that all dependencies are updated before being able to "use" again the project

Comment: After upgrading to IntelliJ 2016.3 I encountered this issue.

Comment: @Trejkaz perhaps because it takes a helluva lot of time.

Comment: @JohnRed a working project which takes a little bit longer to open up, versus a project which is quick to open but doesn't actually work; I'll take the one which is slower to open up.

Comment: I am getting this problem on a Gradle project Import.  This if or recent "`Community Build: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 Build #IC-171.4249.39, built on April 25, 2017`" -- Three **Kotlin** simple "HelloWorld" type projects give the same errors.  Reloading re-importing, cleaning-out the cache hadn't fixed things.  Command line `gradle build` works, they run.  What is it?  Here I was thinking JetBrains were right behind Kotlin?????

Answer (score 80):

I also had a similar problem,
Go to : **View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle**.
 Then press in ***Refresh*** Icon

[image]

Answer (score 21):

This fixed the issue "Please, re-import the Gradle project and try again." for me (IntelliJ Ultimate 17.3.3):

(1) Detached Gradle project:

[image: detach]

(2) Closed the project and (3) re-opened it via File > Open recent. IntelliJ will promt to import the now unlinked Gradle project. (4) Imported it and selected "Use auto-import" in the dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem with my Intellij IDEA version 2016.2 (Mac)

The solution was: In Intellij, Click on "View" then "Tool Windows" then "Gradle" then click on [image]

Answer (score 9):

I had to make sure the **Use auto-import** and the **Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)** were both checked.

```
File > Other Settings > Default Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
```

[image: Intellij Gradle Preferences]

Comment: what do you do if Use default gradle wrapper is greyed out?

Comment: Make sure you have the gradle wrapper installed in your project. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Answer (score 3):

I faced the similar issue when i update my IntelliJ Idea.

To fix it i ran the below command in terminal and it fixed my problem.

```
gradle cleanIdea idea
```

Answer (score 3):

For most people the refresh of Gradle that has already been suggested might solve the issue.

For the others I figured out, that deleting the .idea direcotory and reimporting the project might help.

It can be that your **resources** directory is not added to classpath when creating a project via Spring Initializr. So your application is never loading the application.properties file that you have configured.

To make a quick test if this is the case, add the following to your application.properties file:

```
server.port=8081
```

Now when running your application you should see in the spring boot console output something like this:

```
INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): **8081** (http) with context path ''
```

If your port is still default 8080 and not changed to 8081, your application.properties files is obviously not loading.

You can also check if your application runs with `gradle bootRun` from command line. Which most likely will be work.

**Solution:**

1. Close IntelliJ, then inside your project folder delete the ".idea" folder
2. Reimport your project to IntelliJ like following: "Import Project" -> "select ONLY your build.gradle file to import". (IntelliJ will automatically grab the rest)
3. build and run your application again

See official answer by IntelliJ Support:
[IDEA-221673](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221673?_ga=2.251664522.2072386228.1580473761-1179239385.1560344459)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

1. Close the IntelliJ Idea
2. Delete 'gradle' and '.gradle' folders from the project root
3. Start IntelliJ Idea and import the project as gradle

[image: screensshots before and after]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the root cause was a missing proxy configuration. Once I configured it properly I was able to Refresh gradle projects and it finally downloaded missing files and set up the project correctly.

```
File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > HTTP proxy
```

then

```
View > Tool Windows > Gradle
```

and **Synchronize** button

Answer (score 0):

I went into the IntelliJ Gradle preferences:

```
Menu: Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
```

And under `Project Level Settings`, switched the radio button to ***"Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)"***

Hit the make button, and was in business!

Answer (score -1):

@user1339 I also had the same problem. Please, read this question [Building war with Gradle, Debugging with IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610259/building-war-with-gradle-debugging-with-intellij-idea). It'll be very helpful for you. And recommendation for the 'Make' task. As message said, I should try to re-import the Gradle project and try again. In my case this advice became very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to try to 'Build > Rebuild Project'.[image: screen capture of menu]